# Find how many balls in the drawer if conditional probability of selecting two red balls are 3/4

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are $n$ balls in a drawer, of which $7$ are red. If $2$ balls are chosen randomly, then the probability that both are red is $\frac{3}{4}$. Find $n$.

$\textbf{I need help on how to solve this problem:}$

$P(E|F) = \frac{3}{4}$

$\textit{The number of possible ways there can be two red balls out of 7 balls in the drawer} = P(7,2) = 42$

$P(E \cap F) = \frac{42}{n}$

I'm unable to proceed beyond this. I've arrived at the answer as $56$ by diving $\frac{42}{\frac{3}{4}}$ and it is wrong!

Comment: Please define the events $E$ and $F$ clearly.

Comment: If there are $56$ balls of which $7$ are red, then the probability the first ball would be red is $\frac{7}{56}$ and given that event the probability the second ball (without replacement) is also red would be $\frac{6}{55}$ making the probability of two red balls $\frac{7}{56}\times \frac{6}{55}= \frac{3}{220}$ which is far too small.  So there must have been far fewer balls initially

Comment: The first error I see is that the denominator of $P(F\cap E)$ is much too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you didn’t need conditional probability for this, **GIVEN** that you’re selecting both balls at once and not one by one. Then you need to solve $$\frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}}=\frac 34$$ or $$\frac{21}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=\frac 34$$ so that $\displaystyle n(n-1)=56$ and $$n=8.$$

Note:$\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}=C(n,k)=\ ^nC_k.$

Comment: You better make it: "given that there is no replacement of the first ball". There is no essential difference between selecting "at once" and selecting "one by one".